# Using commons-codec in a stand-alone JAR via Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I've been recently trying to create a simple CLI tool. My flow is as follows:

1. created the project with Maven from the default archetype
   `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false`
2. I build the project with `mvn clean install`. This creates a `targets` folder, containing the `.jar`.
3. To run as `java -jar ./someJar.jar {INPUT}`, I've had to add a few things to `pom.xml`, e.g.,

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but this works fine, *until* I try to add an external library. For example, I've been trying to add murmur3 hashing capability via `commons-codec`, by adding

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

to the `pom.xml`. Source using this is as simple as it gets:

```
package com.someRandomString.app;
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.MurmurHash3;

public class hasherServiceOfSorts {
    public static int murmur3_hash(final String data) {
        return MurmurHash3.hash32(data);
    }
}
```

and, upon invoking `mvn clean install`, actually builds fine. the issue is, when running the `jar`. It fails when invoking this method with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/digest/MurmurHash3
```

indicating the origin `commons-codec` is not part of the baked JAR. My question is, what am I doing wrong/how does one force maven to include external JARs in the final package (if possible). I guess the alternative would be to run via `java -cp some.jar some.class.app`, which I'm trying to avoid (having a single "binary" is very attractive. Thanks!

Comment: When your executable JAR uses libraries, you must add them to the classpath [specified in the JAR's manifest file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) and those JAR files must also be in the right location at runtime. If you want to have a single JAR file with all the dependencies included, then you can use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to make a "fat JAR" = a single JAR file with all the dependencies included inside it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jesper, using https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ did the trick.